# Creating webhooks via GitLab API

Tags: gitlab

Is there any way of creating webhooks in GitLab via API similiar to what we have in GitHub using GitHub API by Koshuke?

Answer (score 19):

You can add, list, edit and delete webhooks.

`POST /projects/:id/hooks`
You can add a webhook with your project ID or with namespace/project_name

Take a look at this http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#add-project-hook

Answer (score 9):

There only seem to be an API (for listing/creating or deleting hooks) for:

- **[system hooks](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/system_hooks.md)**, not webhooks.
  System hooks were [introduced in March 2013 for GitLab 5.0](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/1dd712ddc238d2e6c30be09cb071c8e9b60cfcac).
- [project hooks](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/lib/api/project_hooks.rb) ([documented here](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/projects.html#add-project-hook))

Comment: Any idea how can i get the variable name which contains JSON result sent from GitLab when any project is created? The plugin above is for webhook as asked by OP. I am looking for system hook where i can run a Jenkins job by fetching JSON data sent from GitLab.

Comment: @Technext that is a good question which deserves a spot of its own for *all* contributors to answer to instead of being buried in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. There is already a question posted for my query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25568936/retrieving-post-data-from-web-hook-in-jenkins